# update google play services - Android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I added Google+ Sign in to my app using GoogleApiClient but when I try to Sign In, the app ask to update my Google Play Services on my phone even though is already updated .. I also tried to implement the SignIn using BaseGameUtils and I had the same problem.﻿

I added these lines to Manifest.xml file but still not working

`<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: What's the version the version the app is trying to use?
What's the version the phone has already installed?

Comment: try installing some app from play store which has google plus sign in. See if that is working or the same problem. You can rule out the possibility of code error.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to predict what is the problem, as you doesn't provide enough code. Probably there could be another problem which could be misguiding.

Just follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#install-sdk) & try to get the [sample code](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android) "gplus-quickstart-android" running.

And it doesn't care about the latest update of Google Play Services on your phone.